# When I went to translate "Fraternity Officer" into Latin with a free online dictionary, and I came up with this

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation, motto

The translation the dictionary gave me was "Fraternitas Militaris, which I am not sure is correct. Can someone inform me if I am getting poor information and, what the correct translation would be?" I should note that the context of this is phrase is for a coin that I want to make for every Brother who has served as an officer (chancellor, vice-chancellor, scribe, treasurer, sergeant at arms) in the Fraternity.

Comment: Welcome to the site! A literal translation could be *fraternitatis officialis*, but literal translations are often uglier and less desirable. For a more appropriate answer with explanations, we'd need more context. What role does an "officer" have, exactly? Presumably this is not a government official appointed to oversee fraternities?

Comment: No. This is a Brother who has been elected to a leadership position to oversee various functions he is responsible for in the Fraternity. I would have liked to have one for each position, but funds dictate that I can only have a general coin for my Officers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider using *sodalitas*, rather than the quite rare, but still acceptable *fraternitas*. For 'officer' in the sense that you require, the best word from classical usage is probably *praepositus*.

Together, these would be used in the form *sodalitati praepositus*, literally  'officer for the fraternity'.

Comment: Are you suggesting *praepositus* or *praefectus*?

Comment: I have corrected it!

Comment: So If I wanted to use fraternitas, would the acceptable form be fraternitati? To keep with the grammar of course

Comment: @Max Gatzke Yes. It's the dative singular that you need, which always ends in _-itati_ for words like these, where the nominative endinding is _-itas_.